# Hadoop:how XML files can be stored in HDFS and processed by Mappers?

Tags: xml, hadoop, hdfs

I have just started learning Hadoop and I wanted to confirm my understanding related to 'how XML files can be stored in HDFS and processed by Mappers'.

I have one XML file with XML format like below. Its simple customerlist XML example . Size of this file is 1 GB. Now if I move this file into HDFS, it will be split into 16 blocks (if we maintain the default block size of each split to 64 MB). So there will be 16 mappers executed for processing this file, one for each block.

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <customerList>
       <customer>
        <id></id>
        <name></name>
        <age></age>
        <address></address>
       </customer>
       <customer>
        <id></id>
        <name></name>
        <age></age>
        <address></address>
       </customer>
...
...
```

Now,if I understand correctly, a Mapper of MappReduce job which considers each complete `<customer></customer>` tag for processing might fail because putting this kind of XML file into HDFS using `-put` or `-copyFromLocal` does not guarantee that each split block in HDFS will have `n` number of complete `<customer></customer>` tag in it. Some splits block might end like below.

```
   ...
   ...

       <customer>
        <id></id>
        <name></name>
        <age></age>
        <address></address>
       </customer>
       <customer>
        <id></id>
        <name></name>
```

Now if we want to make sure that each block must have a complete customer tag '`<customer></customer>`', we can go for following solution.

1. **Avro :** Converting each customer XML into Avro type, like record type, and use Avro Serialize and  put this file as 'Avro data file' in HDFS, which supports splittablity and can guarantee a complete Avro record in a block.
2. **Sequence files:** I am not sure about this one but I think we can mark sync points while creating a sequence file, which are used while splitting file into blocks. Here we can mark end of each customer tag '`</customer>`' as sync point, which will guarantee that no customer start tag '`<customer>`' will end up without an end tag in same block.

Can anyone confirm if my understanding is correct or not? And is there any other  way to solve this beside these two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Records do not have to be local to the mapper, it's just more preferable for performance reasons. Most MapReduce input formats will seek past the end of the block to complete the final record of the block. This introduces some remote reading into the process, but as a proportion of the total reads it is typically very low.

The [Mahout XmlInputFormat](https://github.com/apache/mahout/blob/master/integration/src/main/java/org/apache/mahout/text/wikipedia/XmlInputFormat.java) does just this. Each time it runs `next()` to create a new record it scans through from the last completed point and only refuses to return the next record if it determines that it entirely spans outside of the split allocated to the mapper.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is correct expect that the mappers run on the splits derived from blocks rather than complete Block. So the mappers will definitely be more.

So coming to storage of the XML files, they will follow the concept of serialization to enter into HDFS and deserialization while being read(SerDes)
Apart from AVRO there are other SerDes introduced. like thrift etc.